# Showing different results in compiler and online judge (codeforces)

Tags: c

I wrote a program for [this problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/34/B). But it's showing different result in compiler and online judge.

---

When I
**input**

```
5 3
-6 0 35 -2 4
```

It's showing `8` in codeblocks and visual studio. Not in Online judge of codeforces. It's showing `2` There, The value of `count` I guess. You can try yourself. [Try here](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submit)

---

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int arra[101], n, m, i, temp, count=0, earnings=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
 
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arra[i]);
    } 
    //Sorting algorithm (smallest--->biggest)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        for(i=n-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(arra[i]<arra[i-1]){
                temp=arra[i-1];
                arra[i-1]=arra[i];
                arra[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //Now I will search for - integer
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(arra[i]<0){
            earnings+=arra[i];
            count++;
        }
        if(count==m){
            break;
        }
        //What if they are plus? We can not take + items
        if(arra[i]>=0){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",-1*earnings);
```

Comment: This kind of behaviour is almost always caused by bugs in the code resulting in Undefined Behaviour. For example: Consider what happens to `arra[i-1]` on the last iteration when `i` is `0`.

Comment: @kaylum thx, it worked.    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arra[i-1]` with `i=0` is out-of-range and using such out-of-range element invokes *undefined behavior*.

Fix the loop `for(i=n-1; i>=0; i--){` not to cause out-of-range access.

It may be better to use the standard [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function for sorting than writing your own sorting algorithm.